# Php exec() return value 1073740791

Tags: php, windows, xampp, exec, exe

I am trying to run .exe file using exec() in php and get stdout output and use it then in php. Problem is that i get no output as $lines returned and return value as $return is -1073740791. I couldn't find any solution.

Code:

```
  <?php
            if (isset($_GET["query"]) && isset($_GET["number"])) {
                $file = 'src\\infix_to_postfix_and_evaluate.exe';
                $input = $_GET["number"] . ' "' . $_GET["query"] . '"';

                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    echo "<p>file " . $file . " exists</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>file " . $file . " does NOT exists</p>";
                }

                $return = 5;
                $toexec = $file . " " . $input;

                exec($toexec, $lines, $return);
                //$lines = system($toexec, $return);
                var_dump($toexec);
                echo "<br>";
                var_dump($lines);
                echo "<br>";
                var_dump($return);
                echo "<br>";

                foreach ($lines as $item) {
                    echo '<a href="./data/doc' . $item . '.txt">' . 'doc' . $item . '.txt' . "</a><br>";
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>its working but sadly not now (=_=)</p>";
            }
            ?>
```

Output in page in broswer is:

```
file src\infix_to_postfix_and_evaluate.exe exists
string(54) "src\infix_to_postfix_and_evaluate.exe 10 "cat AND dog"" 
array(0) { } 
int(-1073740791)
```

I made "hello world" test.exe and if i change this line:

```
$file = 'src\\test.exe';
```

Output is:

```
file src\test.exe exists
string(29) "src\test.exe 10 "cat AND dog"" 
array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Hello, World!" } 
int(0) 
docHello, World!.txt
```

So text.exe works.

Its wierd when i run my program from terminal from another locations. From src it works and from parent folder it dont.
[terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKD4H.png)

Help me pls! I am on windows using XAMPP with Apache.

PS: This is my first question, sry for English.

Comment: *apparently* your `infix_to_postfix_and_evaluate.exe` uses some data from the "current directory". the `test.exe` probably doesn't. (hence the former dies when called from another directory) one possible solution would be to http://php.net/chdir into the src directory in php before calling the function (without the "src\" then).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i fixed it by putting php file in src\ directory and change file path.